# cant copy text in zeroclipboard

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard

i am using clipper theme and and to copy text into clipboard by using zeroclipboard but it does not copy text.

```
<a href="<?php echo clpr_get_coupon_out_url( $post ); ?>" id="coupon-link-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="coupon-code-link" title="<?php _e( 'Click to copy &amp; open site', APP_TD ); ?>" target="_blank" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo wptexturize( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true ) ); ?>"><span><?php echo $button_text; ?></span></a>
```

i want to copy text in date-clipboard-text and following is my js code

```
jQuery( document ).on('click', '.coupon-code-link', function() {
        alert('hello');
        var couponcode = jQuery(this).data('clipboard-text');
        ZeroClipboard.config( { moviePath: clipper_params.templateurl + '/includes/js/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf' } );
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard( jQuery('.coupon-code-link') );
        clip.on( 'dataRequested', function( client, args ) {
            clip.setText(couponcode);
        });
    });
```

i have loaded zeroclipboard.min.js file in header. I want to copy var couponcode value in clipboard or data-clipboard-text, both have same value

Comment: See this if it helps https://github.com/hussaintamboli/ZeroClipboardDemo

Comment: is it run locally or online? it is not working locally

Comment: It runs locally. Check the instructions. You have to create a site in apache which serves ZeroClipboardDemo as document root.

Comment: I have added zeroClipboardApacheConf in my github repo. It is my apache config. Refer that